# What does tree mean in java TreeMap?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, tree

I am new to java, especially java collections. Java data-structure TreeMap does not have any methods (like getChildren, getParent) to suggest that it holds a hierarchical structure. What is the significance of word tree in the class-name?

Comment: Have you read the official JavaDoc on this Java class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html ?

Comment: Out of votes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33251375/java-why-treemap-is-called-tree-map

Answer (score 1):

In two words, TreeMap means that it is a Map implementation where the data is stored in a tree-like structure.  This leads to the fact that elements are sorted by their keys (TreeMap implements SortedMap).

Here is [good visualisation of red-black tree](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/RedBlack.html).

Other types of maps in Java are HashMap and LinkedHashmap.
You can find differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889777/difference-between-hashmap-linkedhashmap-and-treemap).

Comment: The link you have provided for the red-black tree visualization: http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/RedBlack.html does not work

Comment: I've checked it just now, It works on my Safari and Chrome. You should enter some number into text field in left top corner, near "Insert" button and press "Insert" to start.

Comment: Yes it working! Thanks for the update :)

Answer (score 0):

The "tree" part gives away an implementation detail of the class. According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), `TreeMap` is

> A [Red-Black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) based `NavigableMap` implementation.

The name `OrderedMap` or `SortedMap` would probably be better, but "tree" is good enough to convey the way the class works to its users.

Answer (score 0):

A `TreeMap` is essentially a `Red-black` tree which is a balanced search tree.  The main purpose of this tree is ensure `O(lg(n))` lookup and not modelling a hierarchies.

If you look at the code of TreeMap, you will find that it has TreeMap.Entry which is defined as follows.

```
 static final class Entry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
    K key;
    V value;
    Entry<K,V> left;
    Entry<K,V> right;
    Entry<K,V> parent;
    boolean color = BLACK;
  ..
 }
```

But OOP tells us that implementation details shouldn't be exposed

Answer (score 0):

The data structure is principally a map, not a tree. But the map is implemented using a tree. A TreeMap provides an efficient means of storing key/value pairs in sorted order, and allows rapid retrieval. As it is a map to the user, you don't need to get parent of any node in the tree, or its child, hence no `getParent` or `getChildren` function is available.