# What is this type of plot called?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, seaborn

What is this type of plot called and is there a way to implement it in matplotlib or seaborn?

[image]

Source: https://oec.world/en/profile/country/tkm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called a [Tree map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping). You can create it with [squarify](https://github.com/laserson/squarify).

[Example](https://python-graph-gallery.com/200-basic-treemap-with-python/):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import squarify

squarify.plot(sizes=[13,22,35,5], label=["group A", "group B", "group C", "group D"], alpha=.7 )
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: ... it's not really intuitive for me that it's called treemap but I don't care :D ... perfect answer! Thank you!

Comment: as for the name see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33251428/3944322

Comment: Also plotly suppurts Treemaps https://plotly.com/python/treemaps/